Unable to call component method. Public method [addItem] not found on component
Livewire claims method doesn't exist.
View: wire:click="addItem"
class ShoppingListItemModal extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.shopping-list-item-modal');
    }

    public function addItem()
    {
    }
}

Why is this?

The code shown seems correct, you should post something more to understand the situation better. How do you call the view?
Where is wire:click located?

The code looks correct to me, are you sure you are calling wire:click="addItem" in the right component view? Try checking the blade file and see if the file name is the same as the one specified in the render function.
